# MySQL AVG DATEDIFF GROUP BY (IF datetime IS NULL THEN = NOW())

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to work out the date difference between 2 fields formatted as datetime.

Once the datediff of each row has been found, work out average from GROUP BY department

This is the current query but it does not take into account where dateClosed IS NULL (please see image)

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dateClosed , dateAded) * 1.0), 0) avg
     , department 
  FROM tickets 
 GROUP 
    BY department;
```

.

```
dateAded             dateClosed           dateActivity
2014-07-28 11:43:16  0000-00-00 00:00:00  2014-08-06 10:31:44
```

Therefore I need to include in the query:

`IF dateClosed IS NULL THEN = NOW()`

But im unsure how to do this, i have tried the following but it does not work:

```
SELECT 
round(AVG(DATEDIFF(
CASE WHEN dateClosed IS NULL
THEN SET dateClosed  = NOW()
END
, dateAded) * 1.0), 0) AS avg, department FROM tickets group by department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT round(avg(DATEDIFF( IF( dateClosed =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NOW(), dateClosed) , dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) AS avg, department
FROM tickets
group by department
```